# Google Sheet Email script to email multiple cells of row that was edited in a different cell

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am really struggling with some code I am putting together to email certain cells when a edit takes place on a the same row. The issue I have is I have multiple sheets on the same spreadsheet, and currently it is emailing me when I edit a different sheet. I know i will be doing something stupid but I can not work it out.

I have attached the script, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function onSheetEdit(e) {

  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Specifies the current spreadsheet
  var source_sheet = source.getSheetByName('SHOP Sites In Progress');//Specifies the sheet to monitor for changes
  var range = source_sheet.getDataRange();//Gets the data range for the entire sheet
  var ActiveRow = source_sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();//Identifies the row that the change occurred in
  var columns = "21";//Specifies how many columns of data your sheet has
  var data = source_sheet.getRange(ActiveRow,1,1,21).getValues();//(StartRow,StartColumn,NumberofRowstoGet,NumberofColumnstoGet)
  var emailAddressToNotify = 'test@email.com'
  var columnA = data[0][0];
  var columnB = data[0][1];
  var columnC = data[0][2];
  var columnD = data[0][3];
  var columnE = data[0][4];
  var columnF = data[0][5];
  var columnG = data[0][6];
  var columnH = data[0][7];
  var columnI = data[0][8];
  var columnJ = data[0][9];
  var columnK = data[0][10];
  var columnL = data[0][11];
  var columnM = data[0][12];
  var columnN = data[0][13];
  var columnO = data[0][14];
  var columnP = data[0][15];
  var columnQ = data[0][16];
  var columnR = data[0][17];
  var columnS = data[0][18];
  var columnT = data[0][19];
  var columnU = data[0][20];


  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var emailSubject = 'Shop site in progress ' + 'Customer Name: ' + columnB + ' ' + columnC + ' ' + 'info updated'
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // var emailBody = 'Person1 has approved the item on row ' + range.getRow() + ' of spreadsheet "' + ss.getName() + '".\n\n';
  var emailBody = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + ' Has approved the item on row ' +ActiveRow+  ' of spreadsheet "'  + sheet.getName() + '".\n\n';
  emailBody  += ''
  emailBody  += 'Customer PINCODE : ' + columnA + '\n' ;
  emailBody  += 'Customer Name: ' + columnB + ' ' + columnC +'\n';
  emailBody  += 'Business Name: ' + columnD +'\n\n';  
  emailBody += 'To open the spreadsheet, click this link: ' + ss.getUrl() + '\n\n';
 
  emailBody += '(this is an automatically sent message)';

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddressToNotify, emailSubject, emailBody);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an if condition to test whether or not you are on the desired sheet

```
function onSheetEdit(e) {

    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Specifies the current spreadsheet

    if (source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == 'SHOP Sites In Progress') {

        var source_sheet = source.getSheetByName('SHOP Sites In Progress'); //Specifies the sheet to monitor for changes
        var range = source_sheet.getDataRange(); //Gets the data range for the entire sheet
```

Comment: You are a legend sir. Thanks so much for your help. I had tried a IF command before, but i was clearly putting it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSheetEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='SHOP Sites In Progress') {
    var data=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,21).getValues()[0];
    var emailAddressToNotify='test@email.com';
    var emailSubject=Utilities.formatString('Shop site in progress Customer Name: %s %s info update',data[1],data[2]);
    var emailBody = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + ' Has approved the item on row ' + e.range.rowStart +  ' of spreadsheet "'  + sh.getName() + '".\n\n';
    emailBody  += '';
    emailBody  += 'Customer PINCODE : ' + data[0] + '\n' ;
    emailBody  += 'Customer Name: ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2] +'\n';
    emailBody  += 'Business Name: ' + data[3] +'\n\n';  
    emailBody += 'To open the spreadsheet, click this link: ' + e.source.getUrl() + '\n\n';
    emailBody += '(this is an automatically sent message)';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddressToNotify, emailSubject, emailBody);
  }
}
```